# In an angular app, can TSLint enforce module imports via path mapping iso via relative paths?

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

Say I have the following setup for an angular project:

```
apps/my-app
libs/my-comp/my-lib
```

In the my-app code, I use code from the my-lib. I *could* import the my-lib code via typescript imports, e.g. `import ../../libs/my-comp/my-lib`, but that's ugly and error-prone. Using [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), I can simulate module imports, e.g. `import { MyLibModule} from @my-comp/my-lib`. Much cleaner.

But, can we enforce this? How do we prevent developers from importing code from another module using relative paths? Is there a TSLint rule for this? Should we write custom TSLint code? Has somebody already tried to do this :)?

Answer (score 2):

We have similar setup and we implemented 2 custom lint rules:

- import from `my-lib` with relative import is forbidden
- import from `@my-comp/my-lib` inside library itself is forbidden

Maybe better setup is to use [nx-workspace](https://nrwl.io/nx/guide-nx-workspace) (see Prebuilt Constraints part). It comes with similar rules and adds more:

- Libs cannot imports apps.
- A project loading a library via loadChildren cannot also import it using an ESM import.
- Circular dependencies aren't allowed.
- Libs cannot be imported using relative imports.

This is our implementation of rule that forbids relative import from library. It works, but might have some serious issues that we didn't found out yet (like slowing the lint :)

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';
import * as Lint from 'tslint';

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
    static readonly FAILURE_STRING = `Import should be from '${Rule.SHARED_IMPORT}'`;
    static readonly SHARED_IMPORT = 'my-lib';

    public apply(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): Lint.RuleFailure[] {
        return this.applyWithFunction(sourceFile, walk);
    }
}

function walk(ctx: Lint.WalkContext<void>) {
    return ts.forEachChild(ctx.sourceFile, cb);

    function cb(node: ts.Node): void {
        if (node.kind !== ts.SyntaxKind.ImportDeclaration) {
            return;
        }

        const importLocation = getImportLocation(node.getText());

        if (containsIncorrectImportFromSharedFolder(importLocation)) {
            const locationWidth = importLocation.length + 3;
            const fix = new Lint.Replacement(node.getEnd() - locationWidth, locationWidth, `'${Rule.SHARED_IMPORT}';`);
            return ctx.addFailureAtNode(node, Rule.FAILURE_STRING, fix);
        }

        return ts.forEachChild(node, cb);
    }

    function containsIncorrectImportFromSharedFolder(importLocation: String): boolean {
        return importLocation.indexOf(Rule.SHARED_IMPORT) > -1 && importLocation !== Rule.SHARED_IMPORT;
    }

    function getImportLocation(location: string): string {
        const importLocation = location.match(/'(.*?[^'])'/);
        return importLocation !== null ? importLocation[1] : '';
    }
}
```

You have to compile the rule to `js` with `tsc`:

```
node "node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc" tools/tslint-rules/myLibImportRule.ts
```

and you have to add it to `tslint.json`:

```
"rulesDirectory": [
    ...
    "tools/tslint-rules",
    ...
],
"rules": {
    ...,
    "my-lib-import": true,
    ...
}
```

Rule name is the name of the file `myLibImportRule.js` => `my-lib-import`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I have heard of NX and possibly that is indeed the way to go. But I was first trying to see how feasible this is using the CLI and tslint only.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction how to write such a custom rule that forbids relative imports from another module?

Comment: @DavidBulté i have added our custom rule as example